# How to efficiently paint two QGLWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I have two different `QGLWidget`, and they all have their own shaders.

In case of performance, shall I use two different shaders or I shall write two shaders into one shader and use a uniform value to trigger which shader I should use now?

If So, how can I use one shader in different `QGLWidgets`?